# How to determine data type entered by user?

Tags: types, fortran, user-input, gfortran, fortran95

I am writing a program which simulates the work of an ATM machine.
Basically, I want to display an error message if invalid character is entered. For example :

```
'Please enter your name...'

[here user enters a random **digit**, which is not a character]

[here I want the program to **determine** whether the input type is
*character* or *integer* and then decide what to do next : 
show an error or continue running]
```

I just wonder if there is any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things. The easier is to see whether someone entered a number. Read will try to put the entered values into the variables provided, if it is unable to do that, it will set the `iostat` parameter to a positive number:

```
program determine
    implicit none
    integer :: iNumber
    integer :: io_stat

    do
        print *, "Please enter a number"
        read(*, *, iostat=io_stat) iNumber
        if (io_stat == 0) exit
        print *, "This isn't a number, try again!"
    end do
    print *, "You entered a number ", iNumber
end program determine
```

Of course the other way doesn't work that easy. "Hello" is never an integer, but "12" is certainly a string. So in that case, you'd have to verify the string directly. A simple, quick-and-dirty solution would be something like this:

```
program determine
    implicit none
    character(len=50) :: cName

    do
        print *, "Please enter a name: (A-Za-z)"
        read(*, '(A50)') cName
        if (valid_input(cName)) exit
        print *, "No valid input! Try again!"
    end do

    print *, "You entered the name " // trim(cName)

    contains

        function valid_input(cName)
            implicit none
            character(len=*), intent(in) :: cName
            logical :: valid_input
            integer :: i

            valid_input = .false.

            if (len_trim(cName) == 0) return

            do i = 1, len_trim(cName)
                select case(ichar(cName(i:i)))
                    case(ichar('A'):ichar('Z'))
                        continue
                    case(ichar('a'):ichar('z'))
                        continue
                    case default
                        return
                end select
            end do
            valid_input = .true.
        end function valid_input
end program determine
```

**Update:** As @francescalus points out in a comment to this answer, you can also use the `VERIFY` keyword to check for non-conforming characters in a string. Of course this means that you have to enter every conforming letter into the `SET` string, but it would still be shorter than my `valid_input` method:

```
function valid_input(cName)
    implicit none
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: cName
    logical :: valid_input

    valid_input =                                   &
        (  ( len_trim(cName) > 0 ) .and.            &
           ( verify(trim(cName),                    &
                    'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' // &
                    'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'    &
                   ) == 0                           &
           )                                        &
        )

end function valid_input
```

Now of course this doesn't validate names that have Spaces or other non-standard letters in them. If you need something more complex, you'd be almost at the point where you want to implement regular expressions. See [here](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/regex_module) for an example.

Comment: It seems, perhaps, that `verify` may be a friend here.

Comment: That's why I love Stackexchage. I learn new things every day. Why don't you write your answer? I'll upvote it.

Comment: I used this answer today and verify worked well.  If you want to accept special characters try verify using 0123456789.  iostat is not the best solution in some cases because if you are reading a file it is used to handle end of file.